# Can I know the actual exception caught by the method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a scenario where I call a library method that catches any exception that occurs and re-throws another exception. Is there a way I can get the original exception? Please find a minimal reproducible code below:

```
def f():
    raise KeyError("key not found")

def g():
    try:
        f()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'{e}')
    
try:
    g()
except KeyError:   # Does not work
    print('excepted')
```

Can I get that `KeyError` exception occurred?

Comment: You can just `raise e` in the `except` clause of `g`.

Comment: I think the issue is that `g` is library code that OP doesn't own

Comment: ``g()`` method is not in my control. It comes from library

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want here.

Comment: Would the `traceback` module give you what you need?

Comment: I think the issue would be getting the previous exception/traceback, I think it will be lost within the lib code.

Comment: I can't find anything in `traceback` that gives me the original exception yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you raise an exception in an `except` clause, the new exception's [`__context__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-context) is set to the original exception.

```
try:
    g()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e.__context__))
    print(e.__context__)
```

outputs

```
<class 'KeyError'>
'key not found'
```